# Network switch to router vs direct wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I'm thinking about hard wiring my house from router > switch > device.

What I'm wondering is

1. Would the extra hop make my ping and download slower then direct hardwire router > device (I assume it does but how much slower)

2a. Is it even worth bothering with when using wifi 5Ghz

2b. If it's worth the upgrade my max steam download speed with a 400MB plan is 35-40mbps via 5Ghz what could I reasonably expect on a switch hardwire

I understand this is a hard to answer question due to unknown factors such as other devices connected draining speed but I'm looking for theoretical numbers but if theoretically I'm looking at 5mb differences it's not worth the money IMO.

Comment: the switch won't really cause any particular latency increase. I would recommend using one, since it gives you more options over time as you need to replace equipment. My guess is your plan is 400Mb/s (about 50MB/s), and you are getting 35-40 MB/s from steam. i do recommend maintaining a wired network, for the devices you want to be most reliable, even if you are connecting some or many devices over wifi. if nothing else, you can use the wired network to distribute wifi access points around the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people on here would probably answer this better than me, but ill answer anyways.

First: the switch hop is going to create a negligible latency  which is probably in the microseconds, as the ASIC hardware on it doesn't take long to forward data.

If you are looking to increase your wifi throughput I'd suggest getting a higher gain antennae.

The best option would be to have a 5ghz hardwired access point inside whatever room your trying to push data too as 5ghz doesn't permeate through walls very well. You would need to assign it the same SSID/password and put it into bridge mode. Wiring wise you could run a dedicated line to it or get powerline ethernet, which transmits data over your existing power lines, although this doesn't always work and can get interference from certain "noisy" electrical devices.
You can always return it though if it doesn't work for you.

Of course if possible hardwiring directly into your PC would be best.